# Java code for getting count in the sorted ArrayList for particular range

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, arraylist, count

Need to find the count of the elements in the sorted ArrayList from the given range(x,y). And the count should have count of range elements also if it is in ArrayList.

So for, I have done this by traversing the whole list and getting the count.

**Pseudo-code:**

```
count = 0; 
for (i=0; i<length(list); i++)
{
if (list[i]>= startrange and list[i]<=endrange)
  {
    count = count+1;
  }
}
```

**Current solution is taking more time because input array size is more than 1000000. Help me to optimize the solution.**

**Example:**

Input array looks like this `[1,4,5,8,9,12,16,19,23,26,28,29,30,31,33,35,37]`.

Input range: (12,30)

Output should be like `8`

Comment: So the array is sorted? In all cases?

Comment: Use *binary search* to find index of`12`, then again *binary seacrh* for `30`. The difference `13 - 5  == 8` is the range; time complexity is `O(log(n))`

Comment: There can be more than one solution. The solution I would do is using binary search or similar algorithm. If it is sorted, finding the first element of range is easy. Then you can traverse in a small range. This reduce time complexity. Hope it helps!

Comment: @DmitryBychenko Will only work if the elements corresponding to the start and end of the range are actually in the list.

Comment: @Robby Cornelissen: depends on binary search implementation. Often, binary search either returns the index of item (`>= 0`) or *negative* value which is the *2-complement* of index of an item which is smaller then required https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/arrays-binarysearch-java-examples-set-1/

Comment: @DmitryBychenko Good point! Totally forgot that `Arrays.binarySearch()` will return the insertion point if element not found. If not all values are unique, results might still be wrong though...

Comment: @faxeyo So now we have two questions: 1) is the list sorted, and 2) are all values unique?

Comment: hows about ArrayList.indexof(x2) - ArrayList.indexof(x1) + 1 and check both index exists or not before. Will fail if has duplicates

Comment: Maybe try using the appropriate Java collection classes instead of arrays. Depending on whether they are unique you will need a different class.

Comment: Hi guys, this list is sorted for sure. And there is a chance that values may get repeats and min rangevalue's presence in the list is not guaranteed.

Answer (score 2):

You said *Need to find the count of the elements in the sorted ArrayList from the given range(x,y)*.

So, you can make use of [`binary search`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm) to make your code efficient.

- In binary search, we first have 2 pointers, say `low` and `high`. Now, we start our search from middle element in this range. If the middle element is smaller than required one, we move to the right side of the range `(mid + 1,high)`, else we move to the left side of the range `(low,mid-1)`.
- In this particular case, we have to do 2 binary searches. Let's take `(12,30)`as an example. One is to find the lowest index which has `12` and another binary search to find the highest index which has `30`. Answer for this query would be `highestIndex - lowestIndex + 1`.

**Snippet:**

```
public class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] arr = {1,4,5,8,9,12,16,19,23,26,28,29,30,31,33,35,37};
        int[][] queries = {
            {12,30},
            {-1,37},
            {1,49}
        };

        for(int[] q : queries){
            System.out.println(binarySearch(arr,q[0],q[1]));
        }
    }

    private static int binarySearch(int[] arr,int low,int high){
        return highestIndex(arr,high) - lowestIndex(arr,low) + 1; // + 1 because of 0-based indexing
    }

    private static int highestIndex(int[] arr,int num){
        int low = 0 , high = arr.length - 1;
        while(low <= high){
            int mid = low + (high - low) / 2; // (or (low + high)/2, as it doesn't matter in this context
            if(arr[mid] <= num) low = mid + 1;
            else high = mid - 1;
        }

        return high;
    }

    private static int lowestIndex(int[] arr,int num){
        int low = 0 , high = arr.length - 1;
        while(low <= high){
            int mid = low + (high - low) / 2; // (or (low + high)/2, as it doesn't matter in this context
            if(arr[mid] >= num) high = mid - 1;
            else low = mid + 1;
        }

        return low;
    }
}
```

**Demo:** https://onlinegdb.com/BJ4g3AXXL

- Space Complexity of above code is `O(1)`.
- Time complexity of above code is `O(Q * (log(N) + log(N)))` ~ `O(Q * 2 * log(N))` ~ `O(Q * log(N))` asymptotically where `Q` is number of queries and `N` is size of the array.

Answer (score 1):

Following Java 8 Stream one-liner will work fine & return the result as expected without using cumbersome for-loop .

```
int[] xyz = { 1, 4, 5, 8, 9, 12, 16, 19, 23, 26, 28, 29, 30, 31, 33, 35, 37 };
long elementCountWithinRange = Arrays.stream(xyz).filter(x -> (x > 12 && x <= 31)).count();
    System.out.println(elementCountWithinRange); // will return 8
```

**Note :** Earlier similar answer given by @*Gaurav Dhiman* is incorrect as the expression won't compile as count() method returns a `long` and not an `int` . Also , even if you resolve that it will give below error :

```
The operator >= is undefined for the argument type(s) int[], int
```

To resolve that i have used `Arrays.stream()` instead of `Stream.of()` to create a Stream .

Answer (score 0):

```
int cnt=Stream.of(arr).filter(o->(o>=12&& o<=30)).count();
```

Comment: I can all but guarantee that that solution will be even slower.

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to the question, it's better to add context as to why/how it works. This can help future users learn, and apply that knowledge to their own code. You are also likely to have positive feedback from users in the form of upvotes, when the code is explained.